# What are the consequences of dispatching "different" events under a same name through Google Tag Manager onto the Google Analytics 4?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

Suppose there are a lot of buttons on a website that are categorized in three sets of `A`, `B`, and `C`. The buttons on each set, push a corresponding custom `button_click` event to the `dataLayer`, independently. As indicated below, the "data" include some "columns" (i.e: identically named fields like `button`, `size`, etc. as denoted below). It's all fine and regular so far.

Consider, however, that each set has a different use case, so each of them would have a *few* non-uniform properties, as shown below:

```
dataLayer.push({event: "button_click", button: "b1", size: "L", ...,       service_id:     1,  name: "John" }); // A
dataLayer.push({event: "button_click", button: "b2", size: "S", ...,         language:  "en",  term: "Long" }); // B
dataLayer.push({event: "button_click", button: "b3", size: "M", ...,            color: "red",  item: "Shoe" }); // C
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^        ^^^^       ^^^        ^^^^^^^^^^          ^^^^
//              Same Event Name        |Identically Named Columns |        |Non-uniform Properties|
```

Technically, dispatching *"different"* events under a same name of `button_click`. So, as the first question:

1. What would be the issues with the aforementioned practice in respect to the Google Analytics4?
   What will be the consequences, or what may go wrong?

In the real case scenario, there are more than three sets. Also, there are a lot of these "common columns", and only a few "non-uniform" ones. They all should be entered manually into the Google Tag Manager (GTM). It's obviously cumbersome and irrational; thus, I wonder...

2. Is there a way in GTM to *somehow* group these "common fields" in a package, to avoid repeatedly entering the same records for each and every class of events, over and over again?!

In an attempt to workaround the aforementioned question, I couldn't utilize the `GA4 Configuration` Tag to pack all the "common fields" inside of it, and utilize [its so called "inheritance" feature](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/9442095?hl=en#:%7E:text=GA4%20Event%20tags%20inherit%20the,time%20the%20page%20is%20loaded.). Furthermore I've also encountered with [the issue of "Persistent Values"](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-analytics-4-mistakes/#ga4-config)!

Please shed some light on the matters.

Comment: Just curious. Is the `Non-uniform Properties` can be predicted? Or it will create new property in the future.

Comment: @Darrell_TW Surly, they're all known beforehand; since they're few and "non-uniform", they need to be entered manually, of course. However, I'm concerned about the "uniform ones", that if they were somehow encapsulated in a central place, then if a new property is added to the uniform ones in the future, it'll only need a single change in that central spot (rather than adding the new entry into all the respective modules.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, just blindly dumping all button classes into DL defeats the purpose of DL. GTM is perfectly capable of parsing the clicked HTML element, getting all the classes without DL. In fact, many of those capabilities are in GTM's UI.

DL implies front-end doing some reasonable work, at least bucketing certain buttons into meaningful groups. And maintaining the bucketing logic, so that the analytics team wouldn't need to monitor CSS changes to the site. Theoretically, you can offload the bucketing job to GTM, but now whoever maintains GTM (typically the analytics team), would need to keep an eye on Front-end's changes. Or allow tracking to break on those changes. This is called DOM scraping and it's the lowest quality tracking implementation possible. It is not a good practice and, again, GTM can do the bucketing without front-end pushing anything to DL, so why bother?

Finally, before the DL events get to GA4, they typically should go through GTM. You can cut GTM out with direct gtag.js usage, but that's not the best practice. Ideally, GA4 never sees any of those classes in its data because business stakeholders should never have to map css classes to actual business insights. Also, GA4 has limitations on the number of custom dimensions it can use per event. It's about 50 custom dimensions and 50 custom metrics. Using them on button classes is wasteful, given how little real business value they carry.

Back to your question, although it's not the best practice, there can be some variety of fields for the same event as long as GTM is ready to host the code for proper parsing of all those. Regardless of what you push to DL, it has to be remapped to a network request through GTM, where GTM is capable of doing to your payloads pretty much whatever JS allows. After it, it sends it to GA4, which will ignore all event properties that aren't registered into custom dimensions through its UI.

Here's how you map your events together:

1. Make dataLayer variables for each field except the event like so:
   [image]
2. Now write code that parses these and returns whatever you want to return:
   [image]
   You can do whatever grouping you want there.
3. Finally use your CJS in an event field in your GA4 tag:
   [image]

Make sure you only trigger this tag on `button_click` Data Layer Event trigger. Otherwise it may fail.

Comment: I appreciate your quick response. In my case, the buttons are generated programmatically (without `id`s or specifically-enough CSS classes); thus, I think GTM cannot pinpoint a particular button to do its job, hence the _"bother"_. Also, I've [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75390548/revisions) the post to avoid the confusion made by the "class" literal, were I meant "sets"; pushing to DL is exactly an attempt to group them into _"meaningful groups"_. Could you please elaborate on how GTM can help with the "common fields" to not to be entered manually.

Comment: Again, GTM shouldn't do it. But it can group them with the use of JS variables. JS variables have access to DL variables, so they can parse them and return appropriate groupings. That would just be a bunch of JS on top of DL. The whole DL can be dropped though since it's not useful and then just a click tag would do, with a JS  variable that would read {{Clicked Element}} properties and translate them into groups as needed. IDs are not needed. GTM can always uniquely identify every element on a page through the use of JS and CSS selectors.

Comment: ok, updated with screenshots and walkthrough. I don't exactly know how much you know about GTM, so added a step-by-step process there.

Comment: I actually didn't know about referencing GTM variables in CJS, so thanks for the update. But still, it returns a "single" value entry, that I could've reached the same effect through the DL in the first place (like: `dataLayer.push({event: "button_click", button_params: {button: "b1", size: "L", ...,}, ...});`. Also, in the GA4 "debugView" it's displayed as `[object Object]`, so please tell me _if it's ok to go with the "nested objects" in regard to GA4?_

Comment: Speaking of update; Your first three paragraphs suggest a misunderstanding that CSS classes are used to pinpoint buttons, that's not the case (in my case specifically, no selection is actually even needed, since the buttons send dynamic & runtime-specific content in due time to the DL, no problems there at all); the point of the question is not even about "selecting specific buttons" to track their "click" feedbacks! ...

Comment: ... It simply _asks for elaborations on whether it's ok to dispatch "different" events under a same name to GA4;_ and also asks on _how to minimize (or optimize) the manually cumbersome efforts needed to set it up in GTM._ So, kindly please upgrade those paragraphs to resolve the misunderstandings towards appreciating the favorable concerns.

Comment: when you say different event, you mean the whole payload of the event. The only thing, from GA4's perspective that defines an event is its name. It's completely normal to send different sets of dimensions to GA under the same event names. You will be able then to pull all events with this name and then, let's say, service_id = null (or '') and you'll see all of the instances of the event with no service_id. It's just that we normally don't send technical info to GA.

Comment: You see [Object object] in the debugger since one of the DLVs return an object, so it makes the whole JS var to return an object and that's how the debugger displays objects. The JS variable I used for an example should make more stringification, or better yet more carefully select values from DL, but you don't need it if you still want them to be sent to GA4 as they appear in DL. Just make more DL vars and send them separately in different event parameters in your tag directly from DL. Make sure not to send objects. Only strings and ints. Keep in mind the limitations on event properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are worry about is

If we use one tag and trigger to apply on these datalayers. The parameter is not easy to maintain.

Here is a solution I tested and it can somehow satisfy this scenario.

But it will require to modify the datalayer a bit.

1. Modify the datalayer to following structure.

```
dataLayer.push(
{
    event: "button_click",
    clickTracking:
    {
        button: "b1",
        size: "L",
        service_id: 1,
        name: "John"
    }
});
dataLayer.push(
{
    event: "button_click",
    clickTracking:
    {
        button: "b2",
        size: "S",
        language: "en",
        term: "Long"
    }
});
dataLayer.push(
{
    event: "button_click",
    clickTracking:
    {
        button: "b3",
        size: "M",
        color: "red",
        item: "Shoe"
    }
});
```

As you can see. I add a key `clickTracking` to wrap all the click related information.

2. Create a `datalayer variable` in GTM and remember to set it as **version 1**
   [image]
3. Add every parameters you need as `Custom JavaScript Variable`

```
function(){
  return {{DLV-clickTracking}}["button"]
}
```

---

In GA4 tag. I can just add all parameters I need.
[image]

So here is the result if we use the datalayer and send it to GA4.
[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Why I create another object to wrap is because to prevent the datalayer will inherit to next event. So datalayer version 1 can easily over this problem.
Otherwise you need to set it undefined or null manually.

So if there is a new parameter. Just add another `Custom JavaScript Variable` and add it in the GA4 Event Tag.